# join a sql view and a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I created a view, than, in a stored procedure I want to join it with a table, however I have the error:

> The request for procedure 'vw_Security' failed because 'vw_Security' is a view object.

Here is my sp :

```
BEGIN

  -- declare the tables we will use
  DECLARE @Temp_Order TABLE
  (
    order_id  decimal,
    TRADE_PLACE_ID  decimal,
  )

  DECLARE @Temp_Pos TABLE
  (
    Fund_Type varchar(max),
    Desk_Ticker varchar(max),
  )

  DECLARE @Temp_Tick TABLE
  (
    SyCode varchar(max),
    Group_Name varchar(max)
  )

  INSERT INTO @Temp_Order
  EXEC LNK_xxxx @fromDate = '02/26/2013' ,
          @ToDate  = null, 
          @Trader = '' , 
          @Accts = @fundname    

  INSERT INTO @Temp_Pos
  EXEC LNK_Txxxxxx

  INSERT INTO @Temp_Pos
  EXEC LNK_xxxxx

  ;WITH CTE AS 
  ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT Ticker,CREATE_DATE,COMMENTS,EXEC,POS.Weighted_Avg_Price 
    from @Temp_Order TOR
    LEFT JOIN @Temp_Pos POS ON TOR.TICKER = POS.Desk_Ticker
  )
  SELECT Group_Name 
  From LNK_xxxxxx.dbo.vw_Security 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not joining your view in your existing query. You need to use `JOIN` syntax to join the view with the `CTE`:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
( 
  SELECT DISTINCT Ticker,CREATE_DATE,COMMENTS,EXEC,POS.Weighted_Avg_Price 
  from @Temp_Order TOR
  LEFT JOIN @Temp_Pos POS 
    ON TOR.TICKER = POS.Desk_Ticker
)
SELECT s.Group_Name 
From LNK_xxxxxx.dbo.vw_Security s
JOIN CTE c
  on s.someCol = c.someCol  -- replace the someCol with your columns for joining
```

Comment: Thanks a lot however, if i do that i have the following error :Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

(9 row(s) affected)

(80 row(s) affected)

(2743 row(s) affected)
Msg 2809, Level 18, State 1, Line 1
The request for procedure 'vw' failed because 'vw' is a view object.

Comment: @francopshenri are you able to select directly from your view - `select * from LNK_xxxxxx.dbo.vw_Security`?

Comment: @francopshenri are you sure you created the view?  Can you post the view definition in your original post?